# redirect after ajax call and skip .always

Tags: jquery, redirect, jquery-callback

I have a standard ajax call from jquery as below.

I would like to check if the json array returned is requesting a new page, and if yes, go there and do not execute the .always callback.

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: server_URL + '/index.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: obj

}).done(function (data) {
    if (data['go_location']) {
        window.location.href = data['go_location'];
    } else {
        //other stuff
    }

}).fail(function () {
    alert("ajax error");

}).always(function () {
    //other code
});
```

Comment: What are you performing in `always`?

Comment: Why don't you break and return when success

Comment: Are you saying that the page redirects your, i.e. `30X` HTTP code? or that the JSON has a `go_location` variable?

Comment: JSON has a go_location variable such as browse.html i.e. array['go_location']='browse.html'

Comment: @Dipak not sure what you mean. that might be an answer?

Comment: Well the 'always' will be triggered even before you get the Ajax response. If you want to run some code after the Ajax request then move it inside the Ajax function.

Comment: @Rocky I thought .done is executed first, then after that, .always is executed. are you saying .always is executed first?

Comment: @Ray S. Yes done is executed first but only after receiving the response. But the remaining functions are not. They're executed immediately after triggering the Ajax request. Try moving the code inside the done function.

Comment: i tested it, by putting an alert in each, and the alert in done popped up first, then the alert in .always

Comment: @Ray S. That's because there wasn't a delay in the request. Here all the functions have equal weightage. Read it in plain English and you'll understand. Send Ajax request, if it's done run the done function, if it fails run the fail function but no matter what the result is finally run the always function. So I would say you can move the code in always function to done function right after your if else condition. And in your if statement you can do a return to break the always call.

Comment: @Rocky thank you rocky, just to make sure I understand, does .done always run before .always (assuming success)

Comment: @Ray S. Yes it'll always run in the order you've called. But as I said before the .always will be triggered no matter what your result is (success/failure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As name says **'always'**, **.always()** is executed in both the case either success or failure. You don't wanna execute **.always()** on success state but failure state, which is not possible. You are calling three methods namely **.done()**, **.fail()**, and **.always()** on ajax response. All the method are triggered as soon as ajax is complete [.**done()** and **.alway()** on success otherwise **.fail()** and **.always()**]. We know that jquery/js is asynchronous so, even return statement in any of other method can not stop execution of **.always()**. In your case only option is don't use **.always()** method. Either of the state success or failure, either **.done()** or **.fail()** is executed. So, you can move your **.always()** method statements to these methods if needed.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: server_URL + '/index.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: obj
    }).done(function (data) {
        //Do something if ajax succeeds
        if (data['go_location']) {
            window.location.href = data['go_location'];
        } else {
            //other stuff
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        //Do something if ajax fails
    })
```

Comment: are you saying .done will always run before .always (assuming success of ajax request)?

Comment: Both are triggered in the order they are chained. As I mentioned Jquery is Asynchronous and .always() will not wait for .done()'s termination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you have an `.always` function but I think you could try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: server_URL + '/index.php',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: "json",
  data: obj,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data['go_location']) {
      window.location.href = data['go_location'];
    } else {
      //other stuff
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert("ajax error");
  }
}
```

Comment: is success the same as .done? very unclear from the documentation what the difference is between all these handlers .done .always

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `.done` and `.always` but `.success` gets executed when the server sends a response back to the AJAX call.

Comment: i think .success is deprecated